# Selenium Webdriver Firefox (Geckodriver) does not accept proxy options

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy

Very odd behavior from Firefox (geckodriver) with Selenium webdriver. Given the exact same parameters as Chrome (chromedriver) with Selenium, geckodriver seems to ignore proxy settings and connect directly to the Internet. Any reason why geckodriver operates this way or how to work around it?

```
def selenium_chrome_full(proxy, url)
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ["start-maximized", "--proxy-server=%s" % proxy])
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, capabilities: options)
    driver.get(url)
end

def selenium_firefox_full(proxy, url)
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(args: ["start-maximized", "--proxy-server=%s" % proxy])
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, capabilities: options)
    driver.get(url)
end

proxy = "0.0.0.0:8080"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=whatsmyip"
selenium_firefox_full(proxy, url)
selenium_chrome_full(proxy, url)
```

For a bit of additional context, I also ran a debugger to see the value of options after initialization they are as follows for Firefox and Chrome respectively:

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options:0x000000010814b390 @debugger_address=nil, @options={:args=>["start-maximized", "--proxy-server=0.0.0.0:8080"], :browser_name=>"firefox", :prefs=>{}}, @profile=nil>

#<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options:0x0000000102362150 @options={:args=>["start-maximized", "--proxy-server=0.0.0.0:8080"], :prefs=>{}, :emulation=>{}, :local_state=>{}, :exclude_switches=>[], :perf_logging_prefs=>{}, :window_types=>[], :browser_name=>"chrome"}, @profile=nil, @logging_prefs={}, @encoded_extensions=[], @extensions=[]>
```

Comment: The options are browser specific, IIRC with Firefox you need to set it in the profile as `network.proxy.xxxx` type values

Comment: You are customizing the browser interaction, and the bruises are completely different products with their own settings. Create the proxy directly in the options class